# Basic word guessing game

Tags: java, strings, hangman

After doing a simple coding challenge regarding strings, I realized that I have forgotten a few things about them. As such, I decided to do a few basic string manipulation practices for myself.

One of them, which I found in my old Java assignments, was a word guessing game. Very small, nothing special. As such, I decided to re-implement it. The game works as follows: You enter the "secret" word, and then you have 10 tries to guess it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class guess {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int tries = 0;

        boolean iterated = false;
        String temp = "";
        String holder = "";

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your secret word:");
        String word = keyboard.nextLine();

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter your letter guess");
            String guess = keyboard.nextLine();

            for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i ++) {
                if (guess.equals(Character.toString(word.charAt(i)))) {
                    if(!iterated)
                        temp += Character.toString(word.charAt(i));
                    else {
                        holder = Character.toString(temp.charAt(i)).replace("-", guess);
                        temp = temp.substring(0, i) + holder + temp.substring( i + 1, temp.length());
                    }
                } else {
                    if(!iterated) {
                        temp += "-";
                    }
                }
            }
            tries++;
            iterated = true;
            System.out.println(temp);
            if(temp.equals(word)) {
                System.out.println("You guessed correctly!");
                break;
            }
        }while (tries < 10);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Don't do too much in one loop

> ```
>             for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i ++) {
>                 if (guess.equals(Character.toString(word.charAt(i)))) {
>                     if(!iterated)
>                         temp += Character.toString(word.charAt(i));
>                     else {
>                         holder = Character.toString(temp.charAt(i)).replace("-", guess);
>                         temp = temp.substring(0, i) + holder + temp.substring( i + 1, temp.length());
>                     }
>                 } else {
>                     if(!iterated) {
>                         temp += "-";
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
> ```

In this, you handle two entirely different purposes.  You change the existing string to display any occurrence of the character.  And on the first iteration, you fill in the string with dummy characters.  This may be slightly more efficient on that first iteration, but it is less efficient on every other iteration.  Consider how this code looks without the `!iterated` checks.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i ++) {
                if (guess.equals(Character.toString(word.charAt(i)))) {
                    holder = Character.toString(temp.charAt(i)).replace("-", guess);
                    temp = temp.substring(0, i) + holder + temp.substring( i + 1, temp.length());
                }
            }
```

How much harder is it to do the initial fill?  [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1802915/6660678) suggests something like

```
    String temp;
    if (word.length() > 0) {
        char[] array = new char[word.length()];
        Arrays.fill(array, '-');
        temp = new String(array);
    } else {
        temp = "";
    }
```

Or you could make a method like they do:

```
    String temp = getStringWithLengthAndFilledWithCharacter(word.length(), '-');
```

Or any other variants there.

Which code would you rather read?  Those two simple blocks or one large one?

#### `StringBuilder` to build a string

You use repeated calls to `substring` and string concatenation to build your replacement string.  Behind the scenes, Java probably converts this into a `StringBuilder`.  Why not embrace that and do it yourself?

```
            if (guess.length() != 1) {
                System.out.println("Guesses must each be a single letter.");
                continue;
            }

            char c = guess.charAt(0);
            for (int i = word.indexOf(c); i >= 0; i = word.indexOf(c, i + 1)) {
                temp.setCharAt(i, c);
            }
```

This reduces the two line solution to one even simpler line in the loop.

It also eliminates the need to test that the current index is equal to the guessed character.  This reverses the logic, searching for the guess in the string.

I also added an explanatory message for why multicharacter or empty guesses don't work.  The original just silently goes to the next guess in that instance.

#### Iterate with `for` loops

Your `do`/`while` loop skips the first check at the expense of a more complicated loop.  If you change to a `for` loop, it's easier to read at the expense of one extra comparison.

#### Summary

```
        StringBuilder temp;
        if (word.length() > 0) {
            char[] array = new char[word.length()];
            Arrays.fill(array, '-');
            temp = new StringBuilder(new String(array));
        } else {
            temp = new StringBuilder();
        }

        for (int turn = 0; turn < 10; turn++) {
            System.out.println("Enter your letter guess");
            String guess = keyboard.nextLine();

            if (guess.length() != 1) {
                System.out.println("Guesses must each be a single letter.");
                continue;
            }

            char c = guess.charAt(0);
            for (int i = word.indexOf(c); i >= 0; i = word.indexOf(c, i + 1)) {
                temp.setCharAt(i, c);
            }

            System.out.println(temp.toString());
            if (word.equals(temp.toString())) {
                System.out.println("You guessed correctly!");
                break;
            }
        }
```

It would be more elegant to break this into more methods, but it will work like this.

Comment: Certainly far more succinct and easy to understand than what I had originally, thank you for the explanation and example.